# Radio button redirect url not working

Tags: python, html, django, url

I have two signup pages, student view, and parent view. The default signup url is on the student page http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/student-sign-up/. However, when the parent button is pressed the page redirects to an unknown url at http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/student-sign-up/parent_sign_up.html. I was wondering how to make the button redirect to just http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/parent-sign-up, without the student-sign-up prefix.

HTML

```
<!-- Radio check 1 -->
<div class="form-check form-check-inline radio">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radios" id="radio1" onclick="document.location.href='student_sign_up.html'"
            checked /> Individual
    </label>
</div>

<!-- Radio check 2 -->
<div class="form-check form-check-inline radio">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radios" id="radio2" onclick="document.location.href='parent_sign_up.html'"
        /> Parent of a child under 13
    </label>
</div>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.login_view, name='login'),
    path('student-sign-up/', views.student_sign_up, name='student_sign_up'),
    path('parent-sign-up/', views.parent_sign_up, name='parent_sign_up'),
    path('teacher-sign-up/', views.teacher_sign_up, name='teacher_sign_up'),
    path('reset-password/', views.reset_password, name='reset_password'),
    path('reset-password-after/', views.reset_password2, name='reset_password_after'),
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your both inputs as follows:

```
 <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radios" id="radio1" onclick="document.location.href='/account/student-sign-up/'"
            checked /> Individual


 <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radios" id="radio2" onclick="document.location.href='/account/parent-sign-up/'"
        /> Parent of a child under 13
```